# Forward domain on internal network

Tags: server, apache2, dns, domain-server

I have a ubuntu server where I have a small apache server.I have a domain forwarded to it home.something.com and server1.home.something.com and workstation1.home.something.me and I also have a workstation that also has a apache server running on same port and I need to not change it so can I forward all the packets for workstation1 from server1 on the local network the take the packets and forward them to the client?Sorry for my bad explaination but I'm sick and very frustated.

Comment: How many nic card you have on server, two?

Comment: I have one but I have 4 ips assigned on it and I can use the wireless so I can have two if It's needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to make setup

Topology

```
|--------------------|
| home.something.com |--------------------------|
|--------------------|                          |
                                                |   |----------|
|----------------------------|                  |   |          |
| server1.home.something.com |------------------|---|  server  |-- internet
|----------------------------|                  |   |          |
                                                |   |----------|
|--------------------------------|              |
| workstation1.home.something.me |--------------|
|--------------------------------|
```

- All tree servers have installed `apache`.
- All tree servers listen for connection on port `80`
- All traffic go from `internet`

IP setting

```
- server 
-- internet --
ip: 192.168.1.100
nm: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.1.1
-- lan to home.something.com--
ip: 192.168.2.100
nm: 255.255.255.0
-- lan to server1.home.something.com
ip: 192.168.3.100
nm: 255.255.255.0
-- lan to workstation1.home.something.me
ip: 192.168.4.100
nm: 255.255.255.0


- home.something.com --
ip: 192.168.2.1
nm: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.2.100

- server1.home.something.com
ip: 192.168.3.1
nm: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.3.100

- workstation1.home.something.me
ip: 192.168.4.1
nm: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.4.100
```

`iptables` setup on server

clear existing chains

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

allow all ICMP

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

HTTP

RDR access to `home.something.com`

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: home.something.com" --algo bm -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.1:80
```

then rule to traffic from `192.168.2.1` to internet

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.100
```

RDR access to `server1.home.something.com`

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: server1.home.something.com" --algo bm -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.3.1:80
```

then rule to traffic from `192.168.3.1` to internet

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.3.1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.100
```

RDR access to `workstation1.home.something.me`

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: workstation1.home.something.me" --algo bm -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.3.1:80
```

then rule to traffic from `192.168.4.1` to internet

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.4.1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.100
```

SSH

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

allow forward

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

deny all accept above rules

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

save

```
sudo service iptables save
```

And add rule

```
sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

I'm not sure that this will work, but you can try :)